# Posting pictures to social media

Tags: social-media

Is it legal to post pictures of works completed to social media without the client & homeowners permission?

Comment: Questions regarding legality would depend on the jurisdiction & would be a better fit for https://law.stackexchange.com - assuming you were considerably clearer in your explanation.

Comment: This will depend on your contract with them and possibly on local law and the website rules.  Generally best avoided if you're a pro, IMO.

Comment: If you are concerned about your business being sued, don't ask the internet, ask a lawyer.

Comment: "works completed"  ?   that does not tell us nearly enough to know what you are talking about.  You need to post a detailed and descriptive answer if you want people to know what you are talking about.

Comment: I never understand why someone would jeopardize a good relationship with an existing customer by posting photographs of the client's home against their wishes. Even if the law is on your side, if word gets out that you treat your customers that way, you're going to be looking for a different career in no time.

Answer (score -5):

No it is not legal . You can get sued very easily .

Comment: Not legal where, for whom, under what circumstances? As we have zero information, your answer is of zero use.